# Create new Excel workbook and copy information with certain characteristics

Tags: vba, excel

I'm interning and was given an assignment in VBA, which I know very little about. I found code that is similar to the functions I need and have commented it with my best guesses. If you could help me understand what each piece does and where to replace the generic code with my own information, it would be greatly appreciated!

When patrons have an overdue record, they are sent a spreadsheet with a list of the records they must return and the records' attributes in the following columns.

I need to create a macro which will

- Create a new workbook
- Copy row 1 (headings)
- Copy rows with the same User
- Name the file “UniqueUserrecordsrecall.xlsx”
- Save to C:\Users\xxx\Documents\xxx\xxx

Attributes: Records, Description, Client, Engagement, Days, Date, Type, LOS, Location, State, Final, User.

Workbook Name: RecordsRecall

Worksheet Name: Main

```
Sub details()

'Declaration
Dim thisWB  As String
Dim newWB As String

thisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'?
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("tempsheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0

'CreateTempSheet    
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "tempsheet"

'?    
Sheets("Main").Select

If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    Cells.Select

    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

End If

'Copy User Column    
Columns("L:L").Select
Selection.Copy

'Paste User Column in TempSheet    
Sheets("tempsheet").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'?    
If (Cells(1, 1) = "") Then
    LastRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    If LastRow <> Rows.Count Then
        Range("A1:A" & LastRow - 1).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If

End If

'Apply Unique Filters in Tempsheet    
Columns("A:A").Select
Columns("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=Range("B1"), Unique:=True

'?     
Columns("A:A").Delete

Cells.Select
Selection.Sort _
        Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, _
        MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

lMaxSupp = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For suppno = 2 To lMaxSupp

    Windows(thisWB).Activate

    supName = Sheets("tempsheet").Range("A" & suppno)

    If supName <> "" Then

        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs supName
        newWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

        Windows(thisWB).Activate

        Sheets("Main").Select
        Cells.Select

        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then
            Selection.AutoFilter
        End If

        Selection.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & supName, _
                    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>"

        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        'Copy from TempSheet
        Rows("1:" & LastRow).Copy

        'Paste in newWB in TempSheet
        Windows(newWB).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        'Save and Close newWB
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close

    End If

Next

'Delete TempSheet
Sheets("tempsheet").Delete

Sheets("Main").Select
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this code does not achieve the effect you seek and you do not know where to start fixing it.

You are attempting too much in one go when you do not really know what you are doing.

I suggest you start by writing simple macros each of which achieves one step of your total requirement or adds one step to a previous macro.  If you run into difficulties with one of these macros, you can post it with an explanation of what it does and what you want it to do.  Questions with macros that isolate a single problem get answered very quickly.  I would not know where to start debugging your current macro.

You have an AutoFilter but I cannot see how that selects the records of a patron with an overdue record.  I think that is your first problem: how does the macro know which patron’s records are to be output?  Could this be supName?  Where has this come from?

Can you write a macro that creates an empty workbook and saves it with the desired name?  Call that Macro1.

Write Macro2 by updating Macro1, to rename Sheet1 as “Overdue” or something more meaningful and then delete the other worksheets.

Can you write a macro that uses AutoFilter to select the required records?  Write this as new macro Macro3.

Merge Macro2 and Macro3 and try copying the rows selected by AutoFilter to the new workbook.  The statement `SourceRange.Copy Destination:=FirstDestCell` is likely to be easier to use than `Copy and Paste`.

I hope you can see why little macros which expand your knowledge one step at a time will be an easier path to your objective than trying to debug your current code.